# Place a Figure at the End of Each Chapter (Only if There's Room)

Tags: chapters, books, figure-placement

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\def\asterism{\par\vspace{1.6em}{\centering\scalebox{2.00}{%
  \stackon[-0.5pt]{\bfseries*~*}{\bfseries*}}\par}\vspace{.5em}\par}

\begin{document}
\large

\chapter*{CHAPTER 1.}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{figure*}[b]
  \asterism
\end{figure*}

\chapter*{CHAPTER 2.}
\lipsum[3-4]
\begin{figure*}[b]
  \asterism
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

which is fine. But, also---

[image]

(which is not fine)

QUESTION: How may I place a figure (such as the asterism shown) at the bottom of the last page of each chapter (only if there's room)? So, in the case of the MWE, I would only want to display the figure (asterism) at the end of the first chapter only.

Thank you.

Comment: Will the same figure content be used for all chapters?  If so, the check for size could simply trigger the graphic, so the same single command could finish up every chapter.

Comment: Instead of using a float, just ovelap the bottom of the page.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes; it is intended that the same figure be used for all chapters.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you for your comment, but I'm not sure that I understand it. Are you suggesting that I increase the length of the page when  needed to accommodate the fitting of the figure? I was hoping not to do that. Perhaps you might consider posting an answer so I may see what you mean more clearly.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Regarding, "check for size", do you mean to adjust the size of the figure when it does not fit at the end of the page? How might  a single command do that? Perhaps you might consider posting it as an answer. Many thanks.

Comment: Never mind.  It won't work with footnotes.

Comment: @JohnKormylo No problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could probably use hooks instead of `\chapterend`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\newsavebox{\asterism}
\savebox\asterism{\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\vspace{1.6em}\centering\scalebox{2.00}{%
  \stackon[-0.5pt]{\bfseries*~*}{\bfseries*}}\vspace{.5em}}}

\newlength{\freespace}
\newcommand{\chapterend}{\par
  \setlength{\freespace}{\dimexpr \pagegoal-\pagetotal}%
  \ifdim\freespace > \dimexpr\ht\asterism+\textfloatsep\relax
    \begin{figure}[b]\usebox\asterism\end{figure}%
  \fi}
    
\begin{document}
\large

\chapter*{CHAPTER 1.}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[3]
\footnote{This is a test}
%\footnote{\lipsum[2]}
\chapterend

\chapter*{CHAPTER 2.}
\lipsum[3-4]
\chapterend
\end{document}
```

Comment: Pretty cool! :-)