Trigger a page-breaking decision from the TeX engine
As I understand it, TeX keeps a buffer of contents (boxes) that have been processed already but that have yet to be shipped out in pages, because TeX waits for a bit more input in order to take a better page-breaking decision (dependent on parameters such as stretchability and shrinkability of contents, the value of \widowpenalty and so on).
I’d like to force TeX to “flush” the said buffer, by which I mean, take a page-breaking decision with whatever contents it currently holds, and ship completed pages (the \shipout routine), as if there would be nothing else coming after that; but then, continue adding to the last page as usual, if it has not been shipped. Is it possible?
The reason for this is that I’m trying to insert a page filler at the end of (say) chapters, but this ornament should only be added if there is enough room remaining on the page, after everything else has been typeset; it should not influence how contents is broken into pages. Because of the asynchronous behavior regarding page breaking and shipping, nothing works as hoped. I tried many variations using \pagegoal-\pagetotal and/or package atbegshi and/or page counters, none of them works under all circumstances. “Flushing” contents as I described would sync the current state with page shipping, and let me proceed accurately.
If that’s not clear enough, here is a test suite and my best non-working solution so far; to see where it fails, enable line shrinking (see comment towards the top of this code):
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

% configuration: whether lines should be shrinkable
\def\makeLinesShrinkable{}
%\def\makeLinesShrinkable{y}

% configuration: pick one ornament
\newcommand*{\myOrnament}{\noindent\framebox{\vbox{\noindent\Huge ORNAMENT}}}
%\newcommand*{\myOrnament}{\begin{center}CENTERED ORNAMENT\end{center}}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand*{\ifshrinkable}[2]{%
  \ifx\makeLinesShrinkable\empty%
    #2%
  \else%
    #1%
  \fi%
}

% make lines shrinkable:
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \ifx\makeLinesShrinkable\empty\else%
    \newlength{\baselineshrink}
    \setlength{\baselineshrink}{\dimexpr 1\baselineskip / 32 \relax}
    \newlength{\parshrink}
    \setlength{\parshrink}{\dimexpr 1\baselineshrink / 2 \relax}
    \setlength{\baselineskip}{\glueexpr \baselineskip + 0pt minus \baselineshrink \relax}
    \setlength{\lineskip}{\glueexpr \lineskip + 0pt minus \baselineshrink \relax}
    \setlength{\parskip}{\glueexpr \parskip + 0pt minus \parshrink \relax}
  \fi%
}

\newcounter{myPageCounterBeforeOrnament}
\newcounter{myPageCounterAfterOrnament}
\newcounter{myPageCounterAfterOrnmtPar}
\newcounter{myPageCounterAtShipout}
\newlength{\myAvailableHeightBeforeOrnament}
\newlength{\myAvailableHeightAfterOrnament}
\newlength{\myAvailableHeightAfterOrnmtPar}
\newlength{\myAvailableHeightAtShipout}
\newlength{\myOrnamentHeight}

% compute the minimum height needed for the ornament:
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \settoheight{\myOrnamentHeight}{\vbox{\myOrnament}}%
}

\newcommand*{\setlengthtoavailableheight}[1]{%
  \setlength{#1}{
    \ifdim\pagegoal=\maxdimen
      \textheight
    \else
      \dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal\relax
    \fi
  }%
}

% monitor every page shipout, for testing:
\def\myShipoutHook{%
  \setcounter{myPageCounterAtShipout}{\value{page}}%
  \setlengthtoavailableheight{\myAvailableHeightAtShipout}%
  \PackageWarningNoLine{mytest}{%
    shipout page \thepage\space:
    \MessageBreak ornament height = \the\myOrnamentHeight
    \MessageBreak before ornmt_:
      page = \arabic{myPageCounterBeforeOrnament},
      avail height = \the\myAvailableHeightBeforeOrnament
    \MessageBreak after ornmt__:
      page = \arabic{myPageCounterAfterOrnament},
      avail height = \the\myAvailableHeightAfterOrnament
    \MessageBreak after 2nd par:
      page = \arabic{myPageCounterAfterOrnmtPar},
      avail height = \the\myAvailableHeightAfterOrnmtPar
    \MessageBreak at shipout___:
      page = \arabic{myPageCounterAtShipout},
      avail height = \the\myAvailableHeightAtShipout
  }%
}%

\AtBeginShipout{%
  \myShipoutHook%
}

\newcommand*{\myFiller} {%
  \xdef\myFillerFinished{}%
  \xdef\mustDropOrnament{}%
  \setcounter{myPageCounterBeforeOrnament}{-1}%
  \setcounter{myPageCounterAfterOrnament}{-1}%
  \setcounter{myPageCounterAfterOrnmtPar}{-1}%
  \setcounter{myPageCounterAtShipout}{-1}%
  \setlength{\myAvailableHeightBeforeOrnament}{-9999pt}%
  \setlength{\myAvailableHeightAfterOrnament}{-9999pt}%
  \setlength{\myAvailableHeightAfterOrnmtPar}{-9999pt}%
  \setlength{\myAvailableHeightAtShipout}{-9999pt}%
  \PackageWarningNoLine{mytest}{start myFiller}%
  % end any preceeding paragraph and enter vertical mode:
  \par%
  \PackageWarningNoLine{mytest}{after 1st par, before ornament}%
  % compute stuff:
  \setcounter{myPageCounterBeforeOrnament}{\value{page}}%
  \setlengthtoavailableheight{\myAvailableHeightBeforeOrnament}%
  % catch next shipout if it happens during \myOrnament or \par:
  \AtBeginShipoutNext{%
    \ifx\myFillerFinished\empty%
      \ifdim\myAvailableHeightBeforeOrnament>0pt%
        % if there was still some room left but a shipout happens while
        % processing the ornament, then (assuming the ornament is non-breakable)
        % it means that the ornament cannot fit and is rejected onto
        % next page, alone; in this case, we want to discard it.
        \xdef\mustDropOrnament{y}%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  }%
  % fill the page with the ornament:
  \vspace{\stretch{1}}%
  \myOrnament%
  \vspace{\stretch{1}}%
  \PackageWarningNoLine{mytest}{after ornament, before 2nd par}%
  % compute stuff:
  \setcounter{myPageCounterAfterOrnament}{\value{page}}%
  \setlengthtoavailableheight{\myAvailableHeightAfterOrnament}%
  % add a \par for good measure (TODO: this should probably be removed):
  \par%
  \xdef\myFillerFinished{y}%
  \PackageWarningNoLine{mytest}{after 2nd par, before clearpage}%
  % compute stuff:
  \setcounter{myPageCounterAfterOrnmtPar}{\value{page}}%
  \setlengthtoavailableheight{\myAvailableHeightAfterOrnmtPar}%
  % catch next shipout, which happens during \clearpage:
  \ifx\mustDropOrnament\empty\else%
    \AtBeginShipoutNext{%
      \PackageWarningNoLine{mytest}{ORNAMENT DROPPED}%
      % draw a circle on the to-be-dropped page (for testing):
      \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
        \setlength{\unitlength}{10mm}%
        \put(0.5\paperwidth,-0.5\paperheight){\circle*{10}}%
      }%
      % drop the page (disabled for testing):
      %\addtocounter{page}{-1}%
      %\AtBeginShipoutDiscard{}%
    }%
  \fi%
  % clear page:
  \clearpage%
  \PackageWarningNoLine{mytest}{after clearpage}%
}

% half-line:
\newcommand*{\bla}{labla blabla blabla blabla}
% full line:
\newcommand*{\BLA}{blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabl}
% paragraph:
\newcommand*{\BLABLA}{
  \BLA{}
  \BLA{}
  \BLA{}
  \BLA{}
  \BLA{}
  \BLA{}
  \BLA{}
  \BLA{}
  \bla{}%
  \par
}
% almost-full page:
\newcommand*{\BLABLABLA}{
  \BLABLA{}
  \BLABLA{}
  \BLABLA{}
  \bla{}%
}
% extremely long paragraph:
\newcommand*{\MEGABLA}{
  \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{}
  \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{}
  \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{}
  \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{}
  \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{}
  \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{}
  \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{}
  \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{}
  \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{}
  \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{}
  \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} \BLA{} %\BLA{}
  \bla{}
}
\newcommand*{\mytest}[1]{
  \PackageWarningNoLine{mytest}{%
    ---
    #1
    ----------------------%
    ----------------------%
    ----------------------%
    ----------------------%
    }%
  \textbf{#1:}\par
}



\begin{document}

%-- test 0 -----------------------------------------------------
\mytest{0: plenty of room, ornament}
\BLABLA.
%
\myFiller{}

%-- test 1 -----------------------------------------------------
\mytest{1: enough room at the bottom, ornament}
\BLABLABLA{}
%
\myFiller{}

%-- test 2 -----------------------------------------------------
\mytest{2: \ifshrinkable{shrinked, enough room, ornament}{not enough room, NO ornament}}
\BLABLABLA{}
\BLA{}.
%
\myFiller{}

%-- test 3 -----------------------------------------------------
\mytest{3: \ifshrinkable{shrinked, not enough room, NO ornament}{1 line on next page, ornament}}
\BLABLABLA{}
\BLA{}
\BLA{}.
%
\myFiller{}

%-- test 4 -----------------------------------------------------
\mytest{4: \ifshrinkable{1 line}{2 lines} on next page, ornament}
\BLABLABLA{}
\BLA{}
\BLA{}
\BLA{}.
%
\myFiller{}

%-- test 2b -----------------------------------------------------
\widowpenalty=10000 % !!!

\mytest{2b: \ifshrinkable{shrinked, enough room, ornament}{not enough room, NO ornament}}
\BLABLABLA{}
\BLA{}.
%
\myFiller{}

%-- test 3b -----------------------------------------------------
\mytest{3b: \ifshrinkable{shrinked, not enough room, NO ornament}{1 line on next page, ornament}}
\BLABLABLA{}
\BLA{}
\BLA{}.
%
\myFiller{}

%-- test 4b -----------------------------------------------------
\mytest{4b: 2 lines on next page, ornament}
\BLABLABLA{}
\BLA{}
\BLA{}
\BLA{}.
%
\myFiller{}

%-- test 5 -----------------------------------------------------
\mytest{5: \ifshrinkable{2}{3} lines on next page, ornament}
\BLABLABLA{}
\BLA{}
\BLA{}
\BLA{}
\BLA{}.
%
\myFiller{}

%-- test 6 -----------------------------------------------------
\mytest{6: extremely long paragraph, ornament}
\MEGABLA{}.
%
\myFiller{}

%-- test 7 -----------------------------------------------------
\mytest{7: \ifshrinkable{shrinked, ornament}{extremely long paragraph, NO ornament}}
\MEGABLA{}
\BLA{}.
%
\myFiller{}

%-- test 8 -----------------------------------------------------
\mytest{8: extremely long paragraph, ornament}
\MEGABLA{}
\BLA{}
\BLA{}.
%
\myFiller{}

%-- test 9 -----------------------------------------------------
\mytest{9: extremely long paragraph, ornament}
\MEGABLA{}
\BLA{}
\BLA{}
\BLA{}.
%
\myFiller{}

\end{document}


as far as I can tell you simply want \clearpage to flush the vertical list, and add your filler in the output routine not in the body of the document (at the point \clearpage normally adds \fill glue to allow the flushed page to be short.

Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/707533/place-a-figure-at-the-end-of-each-chapter-only-if-theres-room

@DavidCarlisle thanks, that might be a way to solve my problem indeed. After studying the source code of \clearpage I saw what it does is inserting a \vfil, then setting a very large negative penalty so as to force a page break. IIUC, this penalty triggers the “output routine”. I did not know what it was, but got scared by this. Any hint on how to plug into the output routine to do what you described?
